# Tensorflow multi-label with NCE or sampled softmax

Tags: tensorflow, multilabel-classification

Are there any code examples for using Tensorflow's sampled_softmax_loss or nce_loss functions with multi-label problems? That is, where num_true is more than one?

What follows is my attempt to create a wrapper for nce_loss() and sampled_softmax_loss() based Jeff Chao's work (https://github.com/joelthchao/keras). In the following code, if you change num_true to 1, both samplers work. But with num_true > 1, both samplers throw slightly different exceptions involving tensor shape.

The main program is a simple autoencoder that replicates the class of problem I'm trying to solve: multi-label testing with a huge number of output classes, with a Zipfian distribution. Comments and stack trace at the end.

````
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import keras.layers as layers
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras import initializers,regularizers,constraints
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.engine.base_layer import InputSpec
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras.engine.input_layer import Input

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Nadam, Adam
np.random.seed(10)
import random

def nce_loss_function(weights, biases, labels, inputs, num_sampled, num_classes, num_true):
    if K.learning_phase() == 1:
        loss = tf.nn.nce_loss(weights, biases, labels, inputs, num_sampled, num_classes, num_true,
            partition_strategy="div")
    else:
        logits = tf.matmul(inputs, tf.transpose(weights))
        logits = tf.nn.bias_add(logits, biases)
        labels_one_hot = tf.one_hot(labels, num_classes)
        loss = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            labels=labels_one_hot[:][0][:],
            logits=logits)
        loss = tf.reduce_sum(loss, axis=1)
    return loss

def sampled_softmax_loss_function(weights, biases, labels, inputs, num_sampled, num_classes, num_true):
    if K.learning_phase() == 1:
        return tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights, biases, labels, inputs, num_sampled, num_classes, num_true, 
            partition_strategy="div")
    else:
        logits = tf.matmul(inputs, tf.transpose(weights))
        logits = tf.nn.bias_add(logits, biases)
        labels_one_hot = tf.one_hot(labels, num_classes)
        loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
            labels=labels_one_hot,
            logits=logits)
        return loss

class Sampling(Layer):
    """Regular densely-connected NN layer with various sampling Loss.
    `Sampling` implements the operation:
    `output = dot(input, kernel) + bias`
    `kernel` is a weights matrix created by the layer, and `bias` is a bias vector
    created by the layer. Also, it adds a sampling Loss to the model.
    See [reference](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/gutmann10a/gutmann10a.pdf).
    # Example
    ```python
        inputs = Input(shape=(4,))
        target = Input(shape=(1,))  # sparse format, e.g. [1, 3, 2, 6, ...]
        net = Dense(8)(inputs)
        net = Sampling(units=128, num_sampled=32)([net, target])
        model = Model(inputs=[inputs, target], outputs=net)
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=None)
        x = np.random.rand(1000, 4)
        y = np.random.randint(128, size=1000)
        model.fit([x, y], None)
    ```
    # Arguments
        units: Positive integer, dimensionality of the output space (num classes).
        num_sampled: Positive integer, number of classes to sample in Sampling Loss.
        type: 'sampled_softmax', 'nce'
        num_true: Max # of positive classes, pad to this for variable inputs
        kernel_initializer: Initializer for the `kernel` weights matrix
            (see [initializers](../initializers.md)).
        bias_initializer: Initializer for the bias vector
            (see [initializers](../initializers.md)).
        kernel_regularizer: Regularizer function applied to
            the `kernel` weights matrix
            (see [regularizer](../regularizers.md)).
        bias_regularizer: Regularizer function applied to the bias vector
            (see [regularizer](../regularizers.md)).
        activity_regularizer: Regularizer function applied to
            the output of the layer (its "activation").
            (see [regularizer](../regularizers.md)).
        kernel_constraint: Constraint function applied to
            the `kernel` weights matrix
            (see [constraints](../constraints.md)).
        bias_constraint: Constraint function applied to the bias vector
            (see [constraints](../constraints.md)).
    # Input shape
        Two tensors. First one is 2D tensor with shape: `(batch_size, input_dim)`.
        Second one is 1D tensor with length `batch_size`
    # Output shape
        2D tensor with shape: `(batch_size, units)`.
        For instance, for a 2D input with shape `(batch_size, input_dim)`,
        the output would have shape `(batch_size, units)`.
    """

    def __init__(self,
                 units,
                 num_sampled,
                 type='sampled_softmax',
                 num_true=1,
                 kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 kernel_regularizer=None,
                 bias_regularizer=None,
                 activity_regularizer=None,
                 kernel_constraint=None,
                 bias_constraint=None,
                 **kwargs):
        if 'input_shape' not in kwargs and 'input_dim' in kwargs:
            kwargs['input_shape'] = (kwargs.pop('input_dim'),)
        super(Sampling, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units
        self.num_sampled = num_sampled
        if self.num_sampled > self.units:
            raise Exception('num_sample: {} cannot be greater than units: {}'.format(
                num_sampled, units))
        self.type = type
        if not (self.type == 'nce' or self.type == 'sampled_softmax'):
            raise Exception('type {} is not a valid sampling loss type'.format(type))
        self.num_true = num_true
        self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
        self.bias_initializer = initializers.get(bias_initializer)
        self.kernel_regularizer = regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)
        self.bias_regularizer = regularizers.get(bias_regularizer)
        self.activity_regularizer = regularizers.get(activity_regularizer)
        self.kernel_constraint = constraints.get(kernel_constraint)
        self.bias_constraint = constraints.get(bias_constraint)
        self.input_spec = [InputSpec(min_ndim=2), InputSpec(min_ndim=1)]
        self.supports_masking = True

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 2
        input_dim = input_shape[0][-1]

        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_dim, self.units),
                                      initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                      name='kernel',
                                      regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                                      constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
        self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units,),
                                    initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                                    name='bias',
                                    regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
                                    constraint=self.bias_constraint)
        self.input_spec[0] = InputSpec(min_ndim=2, axes={-1: input_dim})
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs):
        pred, target = inputs
        output = K.dot(pred, self.kernel)
        output = K.bias_add(output, self.bias, data_format='channels_last')

        # TODO : check train or test mode
        if self.type == 'nce':
            nce_loss = nce_loss_function(
                K.transpose(self.kernel), self.bias, target, pred, self.num_sampled, self.units, self.num_true)
            self.add_loss(K.mean(nce_loss))
        else:
            sampled_softmax_loss = sampled_softmax_loss_function(
                K.transpose(self.kernel), self.bias, target, pred, self.num_sampled, self.units, self.num_true)
            self.add_loss(K.mean(sampled_softmax_loss))
        return output

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        assert input_shape and len(input_shape) == 2
        assert input_shape[0][-1]
        output_shape = list(input_shape[0])
        output_shape[-1] = self.units
        return tuple(output_shape)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'units': self.units,
            'num_sampled': self.num_sampled,
            'kernel_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.kernel_initializer),
            'bias_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.bias_initializer),
            'kernel_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.kernel_regularizer),
            'bias_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.bias_regularizer),
            'activity_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.activity_regularizer),
            'kernel_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.kernel_constraint),
            'bias_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.bias_constraint)
        }
        base_config = super(Sampling, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

def fill_zipf(length, num_classes, num_true=1):
  data_onehot = np.zeros((length, num_classes), dtype='float32')
  data_labels = np.zeros((length, num_true), dtype='int32')
  # all indexes outside of num_classes scattered in existing space
  rand = np.random.zipf(1.3, length * num_true) % num_classes
  for i in range(length):
    for j in range(num_true):
      k = rand[i]
      data_onehot[i][k] = 1.0
      data_labels[i][j] = k
  return data_onehot, data_labels

# number of test samples
num_train = 32*500
num_test = 32*500
num_valid = 100
num_epochs = 5
num_hidden = 10
# number of classes
num_classes = 2000
# number of samples for NCE
num_sampled = 24
# number of labels
num_true = 1
# type of negative sampler
sampler_type='sampled_softmax'   

inputs = Input(shape=(num_classes,))
target = Input(shape=(num_true,), dtype=tf.int32)  # sparse format, e.g. [1, 3, 2, 6, ...]
net = Dense(num_classes)(inputs)
net = Dense(num_hidden, activation='relu')(net)
net = Sampling(units=num_classes, num_sampled=num_sampled, type=sampler_type)([net, target])
model = Model(inputs=[inputs, target], outputs=net)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=None, metrics=['binary_crossentropy'])
model.summary()
train_input, train_output = fill_zipf(num_train, num_classes, num_true)
valid_input, valid_output = fill_zipf(num_valid, num_classes, num_true)
history = model.fit([train_input, train_output], None, 
    validation_data=([valid_input, valid_output], None),
    epochs=num_epochs, verbose=2)

test_input, test_output = fill_zipf(num_test, num_classes, num_true)
predicts = model.predict([test_input, test_output], batch_size=32)
count = 0
for test in range(num_test):
  pred = predicts[test]
  imax = np.argmax(pred)
  if imax == test_output[test]:
    count += 1
print("Found {0} out of {1}".format(count/num_true, num_test))
````

This test works for the single-label case, both 'nce' and 'sampled_softmax'. But, when I set num_true to greater than one, both NCE and Sampled Softmax throw a tensor mismatch exception.

```
num_true=3
width=2000
sampler_type='sampled_softmax'
```

With these parameters, for Sampled Softmax, the code throws this exception trace:

```
  File "postable_sampling_tests.py", line 220, in <module>
    epochs=num_epochs, verbose=2)
  File "/opt/ds/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1039, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/opt/ds/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 199, in fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/opt/ds/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2715, in __call__
    return self._call(inputs)
  File "/opt/ds/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2675, in _call
    fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
  File "/opt/ds/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1399, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/opt/ds/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 526, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[32,2000] labels_size=[96,2000]
     [[{{node sampling_1/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits}} = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@train...s_grad/mul"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](sampling_1/BiasAdd_1, sampling_1/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits/Reshape_1)]]
```

32 is the batch_size. Clearly, something is num_true * batch_size but I don't know how to fix this.

If we change the sampler to NCE:

```
num_true=3
width=2000
sampler_type='nce'
```

The final two lines of the exception stack:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,2000] vs. [3,2000]
     [[{{node sampling_1/logistic_loss/mul}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/gradients/sampling_1/logistic_loss/mul_grad/Reshape"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](sampling_1/BiasAdd_1, sampling_1/strided_slice_2)]]
```

In this case, the labels have not been multiplied by batch_size.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get this wrapper system working for multi-label cases?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use samples softmax with multiple labels, you just have to take the mean of each samples softmax

```
  embeddings = tf.get_variable( 'embeddings', 
    initializer= tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))

  softmax_weights = tf.get_variable( 'softmax_weights',
    initializer= tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                         stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))

  softmax_biases = tf.get_variable('softmax_biases', 
    initializer= tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]),  trainable=False )

  embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset) #train data set is

  embed_reshaped = tf.reshape( embed, [batch_size*num_inputs, embedding_size] )

  segments= np.arange(batch_size).repeat(num_inputs)

  averaged_embeds = tf.segment_mean(embed_reshaped, segments, name=None)

  loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds,
                               labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))

  optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss) #Original learning rate was 1.0
```

from

https://github.com/Santosh-Gupta/Research2Vec/blob/master/Research2VecTraining2.ipynb